# Django Newbie: python manage.py syncdb error?

Tags: django, sqlite

Working on the Django tutorial at the moment and got this error when I tried:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Using sqlite3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 281, in _cursor
    self._sqlite_create_connection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 271, in _sqlite_create_connection
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

My settings.py file reads:

```
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/Users/username/django_tutorial/mysite',
```

Anyone know the problem here? it seems like I am putting in the complete file directory, but the databases still couldn't be created? ):

Comment: you have sqlite version 3 in your system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the path to the file, including the file name:

```
    'NAME': '/Users/username/django_tutorial/mysite/data.sqlite',
```

You can also just give it the file name:

```
    'NAME': 'data.sqlite',
```

In that case it will be created in the same directory than the one from which you run `manage.py`.

The best practice is to pass an absolute path, but to ensure this absolute path is created relatively to the settings file. E.G:

```
import os

SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then latter:

```
    'NAME': os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, 'data.sqlite'),
```

Remember that the settings file is a Python file, and that you can use Python code in it.

Comment: I don't think the FULL path is actually necessary for it to work. If you set the name to simply "db", it would create it in the current project location.

Comment: I was under the assumption that SQLite database files are created automatically?

Comment: @zhuyxn: No, you need to tell it what to name the database file. You could have multiple sqlite databases. It needs to know which one to use.

Comment: The full path is not necessary, but the name is the path to the file, it can contains the full path, or only the file name, but not the directory only. The database file IS created automatically, but you must say what name it should have.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of Django newbie mistakes on project's wiki. See this entry: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3

This specific error is common mistake among Django's newbies. See detailed description below.

> **PROBLEM**
>
> You're using SQLite3, your `DATABASE_NAME` is set to the
>   database file's full path, the database file is writeable by Apache,
>   but you still get the above error.
>
> **SOLUTION**
>
> Make sure Apache can also write to the parent directory of
>   the database. SQLite needs to be able to write to this directory.
>
> Make sure each folder of your database file's full path does not start
>   with number, eg. `/www/4myweb/db` (observed on Windows 2000).
>
> If `DATABASE_NAME` is set to something like
>   `'/Users/yourname/Sites/mydjangoproject/db/db'`, make sure you've
>   created the '`db`' directory first.
>
> Make sure your `/tmp` directory is world-writable (an unlikely cause as
>   other thing on your system will also not work). `ls /tmp -ald` should
>   produce `drwxrwxrwt` ....
>
> Make sure the path to the database specified in `settings.py` is a full
>   path.
>
> If you working on windows make also sure that you have the path to the
>   db directory written with double backlashes
>
> ```
> 'C:\\django\\sqlite\\django.db'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need the full path for the name, just put the file name ie "my_db.db". that is assuming you have sqlite3 installed.